# EXTJS Form can not submit twice

Tags: forms, extjs, submit

I need submit a form multi-times, but only the first submit working, the second time, the POST string is empty, does anyone how do I make it work?
thanks!

Comment: Sample code is also helpful to those trying to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the reason, for I disabled all the items in the form after the first submit, if I do not disable them, I could do multi-times submit.